# PHP move_uploaded_file won't work - is_writable and is_dir = true

Tags: php, file, uploading

I am having trouble uploading file on server.

My code:

```
$path = "produkty/$kategorie/$last_id/";
if(!is_dir($path)){
  mkdir($path, 0777, true);
}
if (is_dir($path) && is_writable($path)) { echo "ok"; }
```

And it returned ok.

The upload code looks like this:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uvodniobr"]["tmp_name"], $path."uvodniobr.".$ext)
```

If I echo out:

```
echo $path."uvodniobr.".$ext;
```

It will return this: **produkty/kategorie/35/uvodniobr.png**

Things like checking file size, extension works fine, it just won't upload.
Do you know what could be wrong with my code? Thank you

SOLVED
EDIT: I was trying to upload file over 2MB without changing php.ini in xampp/php/php.ini upload_max_filesize=2M.
Thank you for your answers.

Comment: I hope that when is_writable returns true, there are no more problems with my xampp setting?

Comment: what does your PHP error log say? You look like you're not giving absolute directories for your functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my fault, I forgot to change `upload_max_filesize=2M` to `upload_max_filesize=16M` in xampp/php/php.ini

My bad, sorry and thank you for your effort I really appreciate it.

Comment: If the issue was a PHP.ini setting why have your marked something else as the answer-- this can lead people who read this post in the future to being confused or mis-informed when they have similar issues.

Comment: I need to wait 22 more hours before I can mark this as the answer. Don't worry, I promise I will change it. :)

Answer (score 1):

I guss problem is because you're using relative path in move_uploaded_file while it needs absolute path So 
You should use document_root to get absolute path like this:

```
  $target_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/' .$path; // if not work try    $target_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $path;
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uvodniobr"]["tmp_name"], 
  $target_path."uvodniobr.".$ext);
```

Also it's better to surround it with if to check the result

```
$target_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/' .$path; // if not work try    $target_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $path;
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uvodniobr"]["tmp_name"], 
  $target_path."uvodniobr.".$ext)) {
     echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
     echo "Upload failed";
}
```

Helper link [move_uploaded_file & relative path](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=41989)

Comment: Linking to a bug report is probably not the clearest reference

Comment: Thank you, I changed it so when I echo out: `echo $target_path."uvodniobr.".$ext` it returns **C:/xampp/htdocs/eshop/admin/produkty/kategorie/48/uvodniobr.png** This directory exists on my computer but there is still no image and it returns Upload failed

Comment: Even when i use `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uvodniobr"]["tmp_name"], "C:/xampp/htdocs/eshop/admin/produkty/asd.png");` It still don't work and the folder C:/xampp/htdocs/eshop/admin/produkty/ exists on my computer.

Comment: @ochj1ch is your problem still exists?

Comment: @zhilevan no, thank you so much. It was my bad - I forgot to edit upload_max_size in php.ini, sorry for wasting your time - but you were helpful.